# Can you make someones phone make a call with your phone?

Tags: phone

Ive been called by someone, but when I answer the phone, it makes digital noises and then my phone calls some Nissan dealership. It will literally, after making before stated noises start ringing on my end like I am calling someone. The Nissan dealership will then answer like I called them. What is happening.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like someone is calling you and then connecting you to a car dealership. This has nothing to do with your phone calling someone else, you are only accepting the call.

This is not new and nothing special. This is the default behavior of Google Voice, and other services. Some businesses offer queue call-backs that operate in this manner. There are some advertising businesses that will do this also.

I suggest not answering unknown numbers if you do not want to connect to random businesses.